# Error while using django-multiselectfield

Tags: python, django

While using multiselectfield package into my django app and while running `makemigrations` I had the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Users/pc/Desktop/code 2 copy/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Users/pc/Desktop/code 2 copy/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
django.setup()
File "/Users/pc/Desktop/code 2 copy/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/Users/pc/Desktop/code 2 copy/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/Users/pc/Desktop/code 2 copy/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
module = import_module(entry)
File "/Users/pc/Desktop/code 2 copy/venv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'multiselectfield'
```

I have followed all the instructions on doc and still don't know where is the problem.

**models.py**

```
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

class Meal(models.Model):
restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
category = models.ForeignKey(MealCategory, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
short_description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='meal_images/', blank=False)
price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
extras = MultiSelectField(choices = foodtaskerapp.Extra().get_extras())
def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Extra(models.Model):
extra_n = models.CharField(max_length=200)
meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
extra_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

@property
def is_extra(self):
    return meal.extras == self

def __str__(self):
    return self.extra_n

def get_extras(self):
    return self.extra_n
```

Comment: @houzayfarifai yes I already have it in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: sorry i had a typo and i couldnt edit my last comment, however did you installed your package using `pip3` or `pip` or you used `git clone ...` ?

Comment: @houzayfarifai I used `pip`

Comment: @houzayfarifai it has worked using `git clone ...` thank you that solved my problem

Comment: good to hear that !

Answer (score 1):

1. Have you installed it via PIP?

`$ pip install django-multiselectfield`

2. Be sure that you imported the multiselectfield correctly:

`from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField`

3. Have you referenced it correctly in your model?

`my_field = MultiSelectField(choices=MY_CHOICES)`

For more information see https://pypi.org/project/django-multiselectfield/

If that doesn't work, I'd be interested to see more from your code.